# How can I Get character from user in console and then show it?

Tags: c, printf, scanf

I wrote below code but it did not work and show an error after I input string

```
char Fname[20];
printf("Enter name:");
scanf_s("%19s", Fname);
Printf("%s\n",Fname);
```

The error is : Exception thrown at 0x0F17DDf4

Thanks for your helps

Comment: `scanf_s("%19s", Fname);` --> `scanf_s("%19s", Fname, sizeof(Fname));`

Comment: Thank you so much. It work.

Comment: Printf("%s\n",Fname); >>> printf("%s\n",Fname);

Comment: Why do so many people use the `_s` versions of functions without adding the extra parameters that they require?

Comment: scanf_s() is Microsoft specific function . try to use standard C library function like scanf()

Comment: @EsmaeelE `scanf_s()` is also in the C spec, Annex K.  It differs a bit from MS version.  (sigh)

Comment: Thanks scanf_s work with sizeof.

Comment: I cannot use scanf in studio 2015. it shows warning which I do not know how to avoid it.